# sed how to escape [

Tags: sed

eg. txtfile is just `[`

`sed -i 's/[/linux/' txtfile` (this gives an error unbalanced brackets ([])) after running the command I wanted to replace `[` to `linux`

I tried `\\` at the front, but I don't think it is correct and searched a while couldn't find anything useful. Thanks

Comment: _Please_ don't use `-i` with `sed` unless you know your `sed` expression actually works.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you! Noted!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is escape the `[` using `\`:

```
sed -i 's/\[/linux/' txtfile
```

For completeness, another alternative is to put that `[` inside a `[...]` bracket expression:

```
sed -i 's/[[]/linux/' txtfile
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!